# Обновить значение поля Laravel

Tags: laravel

подскажите как обновить поле `sum` прибавив к нему то что приходит в `$request->sum` ?

```
Branch::where('id', $request->branch_id)->update(
            [
                'sum' => $request->sum
            ]
        );
```

Answer (score 1):

попробуйте так

Branch::where('id',$request->branch_id)->update(['sum' => is_int($request->sum)]);

Comment: Вы не совсем поняли, у модели поле sum текущее 1000 , в $request->sum приходит 500, нужно обновить модель на 1500

Comment: Можете до этого взять значение с бд и в query вместо ['sum' => is_int($request->sum)] написать ['sum' => $request->sum + $sum(пример) ]

Comment: $sum = DB::table('Branch')->where('id',$request->branch_id)->value('sum')

Comment: Branch::where('id',$request->branch_id)->update(['sum' => $request->sum + $sum]);

Comment: так должно работать

Comment: Не работает ошибка Undefined variable: sum

Comment: а вы делали use DB?

Comment: use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

$sum = DB::table('Branch')->where('id', $request->branch_id)->value('sum')
Branch::where('id', $request->branch_id)->update(
            [
                'sum' => $request->sum + $sum
            ]
        );

Comment: Нахрена делать несколько запросов?

Answer (score 0):

```
    $branch = Branch::find($request->branch_id)->incriment('sum', $request->sum);
    $branch->save();
```

или

```
    Branch::find($request->branch_id)->incriment('sum', $request->sum, [
        'updated_at' => Carbon::now()
    ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Хмм... Как вариант без incriment можно попробовать

```
Branch::where('id', $request->branch_id)
    ->update([
        'sum'=> DB::raw('sum+'.$request->get('sum', 0))
]);
```